# Android - JavaPhoenixChannel - EPIPE (Broken pipe)

Tags: android, sockets

I'm trying to use JavaPhoenixChannels (https://github.com/eoinsha/JavaPhoenixChannels) to connect a custom chat server.

I connect socket and it throws an exception with the message `sendto failed: EPIPE (Broken pipe)` after 5 seconds (with `master` version).

When I use `v0.2.0` version, the socket is closed with code `1011`. I've seen the meaning of this code

> 1011 indicates that a server is terminating the connection because
>         it encountered an unexpected condition that prevented it from
>         fulfilling the request.

I'm following the `README` sample to create the connection. What could be wrong? We've tested the socket server with iOS and it works.

```
        final String SOCKET_URL_TEMPLATE = "ws://socket.test.com/socket/websocket?token=%s&vsn=2.0.0";
        String url = String.format(SOCKET_URL_TEMPLATE, "token_xpto");
        socket = new Socket(url);

        socket.onOpen(new ISocketOpenCallback() {
            @Override
            public void onOpen() {

                Log.d("[SOCKET_TEST]", "socket opened");

                //this part connects and join the channel, but the error occurs even without this part      
                //simpleChannelConnection();

            }
        });

        socket.onClose(new ISocketCloseCallback() {
            @Override
            public void onClose() {
                Log.d("[SOCKET_TEST]", "socket closed");
            }
        });

        socket.onError(new IErrorCallback() {
            @Override
            public void onError(String s) {
                Log.d("[SOCKET_TEST]", "socket error - " + s);
            }
        });

        socket.onMessage(new IMessageCallback() {
            @Override
            public void onMessage(Envelope envelope) {
                Log.d("[SOCKET_TEST]", "socket message - " + envelope.toString());
            }
        });

        socket.reconectOnFailure(false);
        socket.connect();
```

Thank you.

Luis

Answer (score 0):

I've discovered the problem. It was the server's version that original lib supports.

Fortunately, there's a fork that have already done this update.

https://github.com/amensia/JavaPhoenixChannels

Thank you.